# Why does a free moving tube with a suction force go towards your hand?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

If you had an L shaped tube that could swing, like a pendulum, forward and backwards. You apply a suction force to the stationary end. If you put your hand close to it, it will be pulled towards your hand, why?

Comment: Can you make a diagram about what set up you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

Consider such scheme :

[image]

According to Bernoulli principle (ignoring force potential term for simplicity),

$$ {\frac {v^{2}}{2}} +{\frac {p}{\rho }}={\textbf {const}} \tag 1,$$

Thus,

$$ {\frac {v^{2}}{2}} +{\frac {P_1}{\rho }}= \frac {P_{2,3}}{\rho} \tag 2,$$

where $v$ is the air flow speed near your hand surface, $P_1$ - static pressure inside the air flow, $P_2, P_3$ static pressure outside the flow (atmospheric pressure).

Hence, due to flowing air into the tube with velocity $\vec v$, static pressure $P_1$ must fall compared to the atmospheric pressures $P_2, P_3$, so that $P_2 = P_3 \gt P_1$. So this suction created sort of vacuum (relatively low pressure) in-between of hand and pipe, which acts like "a glue", effectively letting air masses from both sides to push hand and tube more closely together.